предотвратить закрытие вкладки браузера в javascript
Я хочу предотвращать закрытие вкладки, используя событие onbeforeunload, делая так:
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return confirm("Точно хотите выйти?")
}

Но это срабатывает только при перезагрузке страницы во вкладке, или при попытке перейти по ссылке, но не при закрытии вкладки.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event
